# Calculating values from two rasters using QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, expression, boolean

In QGIS I'm trying to write an expression in the Raster Calculator, but I have failed so far.

It should go like this: R1 and R1 are input rasters, RN is output raster.

- if `R1=0`, OR `R2=0`, then `RN=0`
- `if R2>R1`, then `RN=R1`, if not,
  then `RN=R2`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this nested IF statement in the raster calculator:

```
 if ("R1" = 0 and "R2" = 0, 0, if ("R1" < "R2", "R1", "R2"))
```

Give the name RN (or whatever you want) to the `oputput layer`.